# vb.net how to show list of data with variable column widths?

Tags: vb.net, listview, datagridview

I have a situation where I'm trying to fill a listview (or other control) with data from an ADODB recordset in a windows form. The problem is most rows will have several columns, but some rows will only have 1 column. I am trying to create a POS solution where some lines can be comments. 
example output (simplified for brevity):

line 1: [quantity1], [item1], [item1 description], [item1 price] 
line 2: [comment1]
line 3: [quantity2], [item2], [item2 description], [item2 price] 
line 4: [quantity3], [item3], [item3 description], [item3 price] 
line 5: [comment2]

I would like the comment rows to **span the entire width of the control**.
It is my understanding that a listview will not allow variable column widths like this. Is there a control in vb.net windows forms that will allow this type of formatting? Or is there any other way of achieving this visual output?

Comment: Have you tried loading a `DataTable` from the `ADO` object and assigning that as the `DataSource` to a `DataGridView` control? Most of the work is done for you as far as columns go.

Comment: Maybe a datagridview control is more what I'm looking for, although I don't know how to dynamically merge cells or change cell width at runtime. 
I would like to show lines of an invoice and dynamically change the cell widths of each line depending on whether the line is a comment line or not.. I have a boolean switch on each line to show whether if it's a comment or not. If the switch is true, I would want to set all cell widths except the one containing the comment to zero. Is this possible?

Comment: Just to show I am actively googling for an answer :)
I came across this:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?591414-Merge-cells-in-datagridview-in-vb2008

an overloaded cellPainting event seems like the right direction to go in, but I can't get this to work. It seems like there's enough of a demand for this kind of functionality that there would be some control that natively incorporates this, but I can't find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a custom datagridview control [here](http://www.viblend.com/products.aspx) from viblend that works great.
I'm still finding the ropes with the new control, but I'm able to merge rows on the fly through the following code:

```
    Imports VIBlend.WinForms.DataGridView
    Imports VIBlend.Utilities

    Public Class Form1
        Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
            With viDataGridView1
                .AutoGenerateColumns = True
                'dt is a pre-defined dataTable variable
                .DataSource = dt
                .ColumnsHierarchy.AutoResize()
                'dataTable has 9 columns, first and last columns should be invisible
                'unless the row is a designated row for comments
                .ColumnsHierarchy.Items(0).Width = 0 'this column contains string comment, empty string for non-comment rows
                .ColumnsHierarchy.Items(8).Width = 0 'this column contains boolean flag [isComment]
                .AllowCellMerge = True
                .Refresh()
            End With
        End Sub

        Private Sub viDataGridView1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) _
                                        Handles viDataGridView1.Paint
            Dim colItem As HierarchyItem
            With viDataGridView1
                For Each rowItem In .RowsHierarchy.Items
                    colItem = .ColumnsHierarchy.Items(8) 'column with boolean flag
                    If .CellsArea.GetCellValue(rowItem, colItem).Equals(True) Then
                        'this is a comment line
                        colItem = .ColumnsHierarchy.Items(0)
                        .CellsArea.SetCellSpan(rowItem, colItem, 1, 7)
                    End If
                Next
            End With
        End Sub
    End Class
```